# MySQL Count as {name} and WHERE {name} = X, Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to filter results based on the name assigned on count() and get this:

```
Unknown column 'total_submissions' in 'where clause'

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS patient.*,count(patient_data.id) as total_submissions 
FROM patient 
LEFT JOIN patient_data ON (patient_data.patient_id = patient.id AND patient_data.date_finished IS NOT NULL) 
WHERE patient.doc_id = 2 AND total_submissions = 5 
GROUP BY patient.id 
ORDER BY patient.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,40
```

After more research I did find out about not being able to use a column alias in the WHERE but I am unsure how to execute this query then. I assume it's possible but how would I be able to filter the results based on the count() calculation of the query?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is typically used for this kind of check.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sidenote: (1) In some flavors of SQL, not MySQL, you'd still have to use the full `count(patient_data.id)` expression in the HAVING and not be allowed to use the alias; (2) you can actually have aggregate expressions in the HAVING that are not actually in the SELECT.

Comment: @Uueerdo Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total_submissions` is a column alias *and* the result of an aggregation function.  You need to do that check in a `having`clause:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*, count(pd.id) as total_submissions 
FROM patient p LEFT JOIN
     patient_data pd
     ON pd.patient_id = p.id AND pd.date_finished IS NOT NULL 
WHERE p.doc_id = 2 
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING total_submissions = 5 
ORDER BY p.id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 40;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The condition on `doc_id` should still be in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use column alias  in where clause because the precedence in sql evaluation don't let the db engine know the alias  name when evaluate the where clause

First is evaluated  the FROM clase then the WHERE clause and after the SELECT cluase  .. 
In your case you have an aggregation function related  to yu alias  and this can be evaluated  only after the group by is performed, pratically at the end of query process 
for this reason there is a proper filter based on HAVING that work on the result of the aggreated  query

```
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS patient.*, count(patient_data.id) as total_submissions 
  FROM patient 
  LEFT JOIN patient_data ON (patient_data.patient_id = patient.id AND patient_data.date_finished IS NOT NULL) 
  WHERE patient.doc_id = 2
  GROUP BY patient.id 
  HAVING  total_submissions = 0 
  ORDER BY patient.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,40
```